# How to prove this function has Darboux's property?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   \cos(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\
                                   0 & \text{if $x=0$} \\
  \end{cases}$$

How do I prove this function has Darboux's property? I know  it has it because it has antiderivatives, but how do I prove it otherwise, with intervals maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$. You want to prove that, if $y$ lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there is some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=y$. If $b<0$ or $a>0$, this is clear, by continuity. If $a<0<b$, take some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1{2\pi n}<b$. Then $f\left(\left[\frac1{2\pi n+\pi},\frac1{2\pi n}\right]\right)=[-1,1]$, and therefore there is come $c\in\left[\frac1{2\pi n+\pi},\frac1{2\pi n}\right]$ such that $f(c)=y$. The remaining cases are similar.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to use numbers of the form $\frac{1}{2pin}$ ? They are all positive. Shouldn't we use an interval where we also have $x=0$ ?

Comment: Why?? If there is a solution on $\left[\frac1{2\pi n+\pi},\frac1{2\pi n}\right]$, what else do you need?

Comment: Oh, I think i understand now. The interval can get smaller and smaller and we will always get [-1,1], so it doesn't matter what happens at $x=0$, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it's obvious that it has Darboux's property on any interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a< b\lor a<b<0$.

If $a\le 0<b$, then $f(a),f(b)\in [-1,1]$ anyways and there are some $0<x_1<x_2<b$ such that $f(x_1)=-1$ and $f(x_2)=1$. By the previous remark, every value between $-1$ and $1$ (so a fortiori every value between $\min\{f(a),f(b)\}$ and $\max\{f(a),f(b)\}$) is attained in the interval $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq (a,b)$.

If $a< 0\le b$, then $f(a),f(b)\in [-1,1]$ anyways and there are some $a<x_1<x_2<0$ such that $f(x_1)=-1$ and $f(x_2)=1$. For the same reason as the previous case, every value between $-1$ and $1$ is attained in the interval $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq (a,b)$.